Why closing the lid of my laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 not putting the system to sleep
I have done the following as many help pages suggest to suspend my laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 when the lid is closed.
sudoedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf

and uncommented
HandleLidSwitch=suspend

then
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind

Restarted the system but still this does not work.
Any more suggestions?

"Any more suggestions?" file it as a bug?

Should normally work, but of course there may be something specific with your hardware.

It's dual boot with Windows 11. Sleep works perfectly in Windows 11 when lid closed, but not in Ubuntu 24.04

My logind.conf also does not work in Ubuntu 24.04

Looks like there is no solution for this. This is bug in 24.04. There are other problems too. Many softwares like TeamViewer not getting installed. I have now installed 22.04 and all is working fine including above problem.

I believe it is a bug. It works fine if I'm in KDE (same system). In Gnome, I am also able to put the system to sleep manually and using the power button (by changing settings), so it's a bug with gnome and closing the lid. I don't know if it's related but previously the setting was under gnome tweaks but was removed in later versions and this control doesn't exist anywhere.

I had the issue where my systemd-logind configuration add-in file was being respected by Ubuntu 22.04 and earlier, but does not work in Ubuntu 24.04.
I checked the logs of journalctl -u systemd-logind, and it showed these lines:
/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/lid-close.conf:5: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.

So I had to add [Login] to the top of my add-in file /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/lid-close.conf such that it now looks like this, and it worked.
[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=lock
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=lock
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

Your specific case may be a little different, why not try checking the logs? Like:
sudo journalctl -u systemd-logind

Or check current configurations that are readable:
systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/logind.conf

I hope you'll also find out why things don't work as expected in your system.
